# How to prompt user to select vertex by Abaqus script

Tags: abaqus

I want to select node in viewport and make some operations with it by Abaqus script.Is it possible?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am also interessed about the answer. 
I think this is possible with a mode "AFXPickStep" (you can look at it in the documentation) but I can not tell you more about it because I do not know how to use it.
Thanks in avance for the future answers.